# $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle=0$

Tags: inner-products

$(X,\langle.,.\rangle)$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$. If $x, y \in X$ where the induced norms of $x$ and $y$ are equal, prove that $x+y$ and $x-y$ are orthogonal.

So I want to show that $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle=0$.

I get that: $$\langle x+y,x-y\rangle=\langle x,x \rangle - \langle y,y \rangle.$$ But I don't know how to show this is equal to $0$. I feel like I'm missing something important regarding inner products...

Comment: You have to use the fact that the norms of x and y are equal ;)

Comment: The induced norm is $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$

Comment: @Dark, are they equal even if x is not the same as y?

Comment: It is an assumption on x and y. Two vectors can have the same norm even if they are different: for example x and -x have the same norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is a real inner-product space, there is not conjugation in the inner products, so we have:
$$\langle x+y,x-y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle +\langle x,y\rangle -\langle x,y\rangle - \langle y,y\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle -\langle y,y\rangle=||x||^2-||y||^2=0$$
Since $||x||=||y||$ as stated in the question.